# Adding css and js to struts 2 project

Tags: css, spring, jsp, struts2

Here is my webapp folder structure

[image]

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <link href="../common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <link href="<s:url value ="../common/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I've tried using above methods but still no luck. Same with js files.
I use sturts 2 spring 4 in my project

Comment: Use S2 `<s:url>` tag.

Comment: Already tried. It doesn't seem to work